# GetCurrentRow() in Devexpress XtraReports not working any more

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

does anyone know why GetCurrentRow() in xtrareports, devexpress 10.1.4 doesn't work anymore? It always returns a null, in the previous versions it used to return the current row on the data source. It's being used in a subreport context.

Answer (score 0):

We are unaware of this issue.  I would suggest that you install the latest (10.1.5) version and check how it works.  If you still see the issue, post a bug report to DevExpress support team (http:/devexpress.com/support/center).